# Google Apps Script: how to get the number of columns in a sheet? (alternative way)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to use the number of columns in a sheet in a for loop. I could use a function like this, to stop when the loop finds the first empty column:

```
function getRowAsArray(sheet, row) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 99);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var columns = [];

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    Logger.log("Got row", row);

    for(var l=0; l<99; l++) {
        var col = row[l];
        // First empty column interrupts
        if(!col) {
            break;
        }

        columns.push(col);
    }
  }

  return columns;
}
```

But I'd like an alternative function which use the number of columns in the sheet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en):
[getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getLastColumn%28%29) and to get the maximum count including empty ones, [getMaxColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getMaxColumns%28%29).